# What does it mean that I have the url for a web service in app.config but not in web.config file?

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, url, wsdl

Sometime ago for my asp.net application I have added a web service.

After some time I wanted to modify its url. And when I was investigating the code, I have found out that the url of the web service in app.config file.

Should not it be in web.config file as I am not developing a windows application?

How should I explain this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the web service in the web project/app of your solution or in another project referenced by the web project e.g. a business layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **web apps**, the application reads values from **web.config** and not any other config file. Some times when you add something that needs a config, to your project (like an EF model or web service) it adds a app.config file. Usually it happens when you add it in an other project(**dll**) in your solution.

Update:

as jisaak said, you have to copy any values you need from app.config to web.config manually.

Comment: I think its also important to note that you will have to copy over any references for EF/Web Service in the app.config to your web.config file since the dll's app.config file is not referenced.